# OpenCV deep learning face detection assertion error in function 'cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes'

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, caffe, face-detection

I followed [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/02/26/face-detection-with-opencv-and-deep-learning/) to implement face detection from [image](https://ibb.co/0j3ywk4) with OpenCV and deep learning SSD framework.

```
modelFile = "./ssd/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
configFile = "./ssd/deploy.prototxt"
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(configFile, modelFile)
image = cv2.imread("face.jpg")
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 1.0, (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()
```

but `detections = net.forward()` returns error:

`error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\layers\convolution_layer.cpp:236: error: (-215:Assertion failed) blobs.size() != 0 in function 'cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes'`

Still looking for more information, but have no idea if it's mistake in code or bug in library... Anyone knows what could cause problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share `face.jpg`?

Comment: @keineahnung2345 updated question, image sample - https://ibb.co/0j3ywk4

Comment: my guess would be the image is not in the same directory as your script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem using both OpenCV 3.4.2 and OpenCV 4.0.0.

Here's what I get:

[image]

P.S. I download res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/dnn_samples_face_detector_20170830/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel and deploy.prototxt from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/raw/3.4.0/samples/dnn/face_detector/deploy.prototxt.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know where your problem is, please check these two files "deploy.prototxt" and "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel" under your ssd folder. If the size of the files aren't zero, it might happen that your download was blocked/interrupted (blocked by firewall, connection failures etc) compare it with the original size. If the size is zero then it did not download at all.

In both the cases,
Please go to "https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/face_detector/deploy.prototxt" github repository

and

"https://github.com/opencv/opencv_3rdparty/raw/dnn_samples_face_detector_20170830/res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel" to download the two files with the same name and replace them.

Or you may use the same source you were using before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when using grayscale images. 
After reading the images in color, the error was solved.