# Why do I get error - Number of input channels should be multiple of 3 but got 1 in function 'cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes'

Tags: python, opencv

When I run this code, I get an error saying - Number of input channels should be multiple of 3 but got 1 in function 'cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes'

Here is my code:

```
faces_rect = haar_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
gender_model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("gender_deploy.prototxt", "gender_net 
(1).caffemodel")
age_model = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe("age_deploy.prototxt", "age_net.caffemodel")
for (x,y,w,h) in faces_rect:
faces_roi = gray[y:y+h,x:x+h]

label, confidence = face_recognizer.predict(faces_roi)
print(f'Label = {people[label]} with a confidence of {confidence}')
img_blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(faces_roi)
age_model.setInput(img_blob)
age_dist = age_model.forward()[0]
apparent_predictions = round(np.sum(age_dist * output_indexes), 2)
print("Apparent age: ", apparent_predictions)

# ---------------------------

gender_model.setInput(img_blob)
gender_class = gender_model.forward()[0]
gender = 'Woman ' if np.argmax(gender_class) == 0 else 'Man'
print("Gender: ", gender)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I get error in line - age_dist = age_model.forward()[0]

Comment: What is the shape of `faces_roi` ? Maybe try reading in an RGB with 3 channels instead of 1 channel gray image

Comment: faces_roi is the part of image that the cv is reading for face recognition, when i convert it to rgb, I get one more error -

Comment: cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\layers\fully_connected_layer.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) srcMat.dims == 2 && srcMat.cols == weights.cols && dstMat.rows == srcMat.rows && dstMat.cols == weights.rows && srcMat.type() == weights.type() && weights.type() == dstMat.type() && srcMat.type() == CV_32F && (biasMat.empty() || (biasMat.type() == srcMat.type() && biasMat.isContinuous() && (int)biasMat.total() == dstMat.cols)) in function 'cv::dnn::FullyConnectedLayerImpl::FullyConnected::run'

Comment: maybe this is useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54660069/opencv-deep-learning-face-detection-assertion-error-in-function-cvdnnconvol

Comment: no, that did not helped