# Error de OpenCV: ConvolutionLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes() - Assertion failed

Tags: image-processing, face-detection

I'm encountering an error when trying to use an age detection script based on OpenCV, which I found on the PyImageSearch website ([link](https://pyimagesearch.com/2020/04/13/opencv-age-detection-with-deep-learning/)).

Here's the relevant part of the script:

```
# load the input image and construct an input blob for the image

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1.0, (300, 300), (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))
# pass the blob through the network and obtain the face detections
print("[INFO] computing face detections...")
print("First Blob: {}".format(blob.shape))
faceNet.setInput(blob)
detections = faceNet.forward()
```

However, when I run the script with the following command:

```
python detect_age.py --image images/samuel_l_jackson.png --face face_detector --age age_detector
```

I consistently get the following error:

```
[ERROR:0@0.157] global net_impl.cpp:1169 cv::dnn::dnn4_v20231225::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively OPENCV/DNN: [Convolution]:(conv1): getMemoryShapes() throws exception. inputs=1 outputs=0/1 blobs=0
[ERROR:0@0.163] global net_impl.cpp:1172 cv::dnn::dnn4_v20231225::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively     input[0] = [ 1 3 224 224 ]
[ERROR:0@0.168] global net_impl.cpp:1182 cv::dnn::dnn4_v20231225::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively Exception message: OpenCV(4.9.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\layers\convolution_layer.cpp:368: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !blobs.empty() || inputs.size() > 1 in function 'cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::getMemoryShapes'
```

I've verified that the input image and necessary files for the face and age detection models are all correctly specified and accessible. Can anyone help me understand and fix this error?

Comment: I found a solution to the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54660069/opencv-deep-learning-face-detection-assertion-error-in-function-cvdnnconvol). Hope it works!

Comment: Thank you man!!!!!! You are the greatest of all time, I bet you like LeBron, because you are THE CHOSEN ONE.